What does guiding tooling mean in the context of Angular Pipe Transform Interface
I'm reviewing Angular Pipes, filling in quite a few gaps.  In this link Angular Pipes, is the text

The PipeTransform interface
The transform method is essential to a pipe. The PipeTransform interface defines that method and guides both tooling and the compiler. Technically, it's optional; Angular looks for and executes the transform method regardless.

To better understand just what this means, here is the very comprehensive definition of tooling in Angular:

What is end-to-end tooling in Angular?
End-to-End Tooling: Explanation: Angular provides a comprehensive set of tools for developing, testing, and deploying applications. This end-to-end tooling includes the Angular CLI (Command Line Interface), which simplifies various tasks such as project setup, code generation, testing, and deployment.

Here is the link for this definition of tooling:
End to End Tooling definition
Of course, this throws the kitchen sink at the question.  I'm sure there's a more granular concept here.
I'm totally missing the concept of 'guides both tooling and the compiler' -- just the 'guides tooling' part.  Guiding the compiler is obvious -- the code has to be transformed at some point to machine level instructions that do what the programmer intends.  That's still very vague for 'guiding the compiler' but is close enough for road work.
So, for the part 'guiding the tooling', from the comprehensive definition I sort of get it.  But what's the more 'pipe specific' guiding of tooling here?
Thanks!

When I click on Current Angular in this article, it takes me to some fancy graphics, not to the latest and greatest Pipes tutorial.
Also, the downloaded code here https://v2.angular.io/resources/zips/pipes/pipes.zip does not work.
Correct me -- should be able to browse to the app.module.html and bring up the site, yes?
This does not happen.
Another question -- how do you bring up a basic angular template, just like one would in asp.net?

Yep -- as this is old, I suppose the code would not work unless unzipped into an empty angular app in Visual Studio.  Download modules with npm install, etc.
I was hoping just to get some practice with pipes.  Can't find any good tutorial with working downloadable code to just plink away.

It could be worded more clear. What I think they mean by "tooling" is that IDEs can use this information to guide the developer. So if you start typing tra, that the IDE can offer you the transform function as a suggestion. This is not only pipe specific, it's more a general concept of TypeScript interfaces.
This definition of "Tooling in Angular" from the given blog entry is not from the Angular team, so you should use it with caution.
Also note that this is a very old version of the Angular Docs, which was released shortly after it became stable. Since then a lot more work has been put into the docs.
